# Prevent never-ending sub documents in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js, postdata

In nodeJS, we can get POST data by this:

```
<input type="text" name="doc[a]"/>
```

`var doc = req.body.doc;`

When I get 'doc', I insert into MongoDB using native-mongodb collection.insert(doc, ..)

I wonder if when doing POST request, I inject this kind of data

```
doc[a][b][c][d][e][f][g][h][i][j][.]... = xxxx
doc[b] = yyy
doc[e] = zzz
```

I only need doc[a] buy would end up having doc.a.b.c.d.f.g... like this in Node and MongoDB right?
What is a good solution to prevent that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about MongoDB Injection can be found at the [official docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Do+I+Have+to+Worry+About+SQL+Injection). and Here are some [security guidelines from PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.security.php). The solution is pretty simple - **type cast it to string**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So every times, I need to parseInt(doc.a) for Int, String(doc.a) for String and using for(k in doc.arr) doc.arr[k] = String(doc.arr[k]) for the array of string.

Comment: Yes. Injections work when you are treating the user's data not just as value for the database command but as part of the command.